# Why tritium doesn't undergo $\beta^-$ decay to form $He^3$?

Tags: radioactivity

In my textbook it is written that Tritium is an isotope of hydrogen whose nucleus Triton contains 2 neutrons and 1 proton. Free neutrons decay into p + electron + anti-neutrino . If
one of the neutrons in Triton decays, it would transform into $He^3$
nucleus. This does not happen and the reason is given to be that both the neutrons in triton have to decay simultaneously resulting in a nucleus with 3 protons, which is not a $He^3$
nucleus.

**But, why is necessary that both the nucleus should decay simultaneously?**

Comment: [It does](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=10003). Halflife a bit over 12 years. Who told you it doesn't?

Comment: @dmckee Sir can you please explain?I'm not able to understand from the given link.

Comment: That is from [an on-line table of the isotopes](http://ie.lbl.gov/education/isotopes.htm) (useful link, BTW). The symbol at the top left is $^3_1\mathrm{H}$, which is to say tritium. The table lists the decay mode b- (which means $\beta^-$) as having a 100% branching ratio and no other modes (i.e. all decays occur in that channel) and gives the halflife. For more complicated isotopes there is a lot more data in the page, but tritium is simple.

Comment: There is no double beta decay mode listed as it would be energetically disfavored.